# Setting up Picasa account permission

Tags: php, permissions, picasa

I have a php script that shows all the picasa public albums by using the email address (Username). It works fine on some accounts. It has a problem with one account and i traced the code and found that it outputs "Invalid User".

I logged into the account and check for public albums and i can see a public album. I have also checked the rss url of the public albums and it works fine and atlast i found that it is working only when i am login to the particular user. If i use the same url in another browser without login it outputs invalid user.

I knew google changed some policies but i couldn't figure out how to remove that restriction on public albums. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem. The google+ profile for that particular account was suspended due to the name. Once it is fixed everything is working well. I hope this answer will help for someone out there. Thanks